# disable onmouseout function when onclick event is activated

Tags: javascript, image, dreamweaver, swap

My code looks like this using Image Swap of Dreamweaver.

```
<a href = "#"> <img src="images/leistungen.png" alt="leistungen" name="leistungen"
 width="162" height="38" id="leistungen"
onclick="MM_swapImage('home','','images/home_orig.png','philosophie','', 'images/philosophie.png','kontakt','','images/kontakt.png','body_layout','','images/body_leistungen.png',0)"
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('leistungen','','images/leistungen_onclick.png',1)"
onmouseout="roll()" /></a>
```

then I have this function

```
function roll(){
var temp; temp.src = 'images/leistungen_onclick.png';
if(document.leistungen.src == temp.src){return false;}
else {document.leistungen.src = 'images/leistungen.png';}
}
```

I want the roll() function to detect if the image was clicked or not..
so my solution is to check if the image source is leistungen_onclick.png if not then perform the onmouseover function..

```
if(document.leistungen.src == temp.src){return false;}
```

never executed...
My question is.. what is the proper way to determine the image source of an image? or is there a simple way to disable onmouseover function when the onclick function is executed?

Thank you very much!
Jr
EDIT: sorry I don't know how to make it a code tag. Now I know.

Comment: Please reformat your code sections by indenting 4 spaces. I'd do it myself but I can't edit other peoples posts yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="#" img src="images/leistungen.png" alt="leistungen" name="leistungen"      
width="162" height="38" id="leistungen"    
onclick="MM_swapImage('home','','images/home_orig.png','philosophie','','images/philosophie.png','kontakt','','images/kontakt.png','body_layout','','images/body_leistungen.png',0)`;this.onmouseout=''" 
onmouseover="MM_swapImage('leistungen','','images/leistungen_onclick.png',1)"         
onmouseout="document.leistungen.src = 'images/leistungen.png';">Text</a>
```